# Resolving JS conflicts between 2 components

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I've been using a very nice slider component from Egor Khmelev ([documentation](http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/EN/332/476ae700/jslider-is-easy-to-use-and-multifunctional-jquery-plugin-jslider.html), [github](https://github.com/egorkhmelev)) but recently decided to add a date and time picker (I'm primarily using it just for the timepicker functionality for the moment) from Trent Richardson ([documentation](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), [github](http://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon)). The problem is they both defined a function called "slider" and the implementations conflict. Is there any way to isolate these such that the conflict can be avoided but still allow for reasonably easy updates of the individual components as updates become available?

Comment: Are you sure the timepicker adds a `slider` method to the jQuery namespace? I can see `sliderAccess` but not `slider`.

Comment: Trent Richardson's plugin merely uses the "standard" jQuery UI slider component. If you're depending on jQuery UI at all, I'd just stick with their versions of components consistently; trying to mix and match can only lead to trouble. For what it's worth, given how recent Egor's plugin is, I consider not avoiding the clash with jQuery UI (or otherwise dealing with compatibility) a mistake on his part.

Comment: As a quick fix, you could try hacking the first plugin and just renaming the function to "jslider"

Comment: @David, I think it's the slider function that comes with range-slider from Egor that's conflicting with Trent's plugin which uses the jQuery UI's slider.

Comment: @millimoose, yes I was thinking of something like that. I've posted an issue to Egor on github to see if he has another suggestion. If not then it may be "hack time".

Comment: @ken Honestly, it shouldn't be too hard to do this compatibly, copying the approach of `jQuery.noConflict()`. Basically: rename the functions to something unlikely to cause a conflict, like `egork_slider()`, and use that name internally. Then to avoid breaking old code, alias that function to `slider` in `jQuery.fn`, making sure to back up the previous value of that property. Then define a new function `egork_slider_noConflict()` that will restore the value of `$.fn.slider` and keep the nonconflicting name. (Feel free to copy this into the issue.)